# Python Multiprocessing/EM

Tags: python, mapreduce, machine-learning, multiprocessing, machine-translation

I did a machine learning Expectation Maximization algorithm in Python, basically an implementation of IBM Model1 for doing machine translation ( [here is my GitHub](https://github.com/msnorth/Model1) if you want to look at the code) and it works, but reeeaaaaallly sloowwwlly. I'm taking a class now in parallel computing and I was wondering if I could use [Python Multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) to reach convergence faster. Can anyone give me any pointers or tips? I don't even know where to start.

EDIT: I was reading around and found  [this paper](http://www2007.org/papers/paper570.pdf) on using EM with MapReduce to do parallelization -- maybe this is a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your problem is that Python is really slow. Remember, your code is executing in an interpreter. When you do code (such as line 82) where you perform a numerical computation one element at a time, you have that one computation - and all the overhead of the Python interpreter.

The first thing you will want to do is vectorize you code with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org). Unlike your normal python code, numpy is calling out to precompiled efficient binary code. The more work you can hide into numpy, the less time you will waist in the interpreter.

Once you vectorize your code, you can then start profiling it if its still too slow. You should be able to find a lot of simple examples on how to [vectorize python, and some of the alternative options](http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.com/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html).

EDIT: Let me clarify, that parallelizing inherently slow code is mostly pointless. First, is the issue that parallelizing slow code gives the false impression that you have made an improvement. The "scaling up" of parallel code should always be done against the fastest possible single threaded version of the same code (within reason, no need to write everything in assembly before starting any parallel code). For example, consider a lock under contention. The more threads fighting for the lock, the slower the code will run, and you will get no (or negative) performance gains. One way to reduce contention for the lock is to simply slow down the code competing for the lock. This makes it appear as if there is no overhead from lock contention, when in actuality - you have no improvements because the fastest single threaded version of your code will outperform your parallel code.

Also, python really isn't a great language to learn how to write parallel code in. Python has the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) , which essentially forces all multithreaded code in python to run as if there was but one CPU core. This means bizarre hacks (such as the one you linked) must be done, which have their own additional drawbacks and issues (there are times where such tricks are needed / used, but they shouldn't be the default for running code on a single machine). Don't expect what you learn writing any parallel python code to carry over to other languages or help you with your course.

Comment: Thank you for your realistic (if depressing) answer. What would you recommend as a good exercise about parallelizing code? In what language?

Comment: Depends on what your goals are. While OpenMP (C/C++) is probably the elephant in the room, its not exactly elegant or easy to pick up (a lot of learning OpenMP instead of learning Parallel computation).

I, personally, feel like Java is a good language for getting started in parallel computing. It provides a number of primitives (Locks, Semaphores, Atomic ints/longs) so that you can focus on implementing the algorithm, without tooo much other stuff. 

Ultimately, implement parallel versions of algorithms you know (BFS, DFS, Dijkstra's). Just remember parallel code is hard, you'll probably want

Comment: a book. (comment was too long)

Comment: I know C/C++ and I think I would prefer that to Java because it's a bit more transparent what the compiler is doing. Could you recommend a good book?

Comment: The book I used was http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0201648652,00%2ben-USS_01DBC.html for my course work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have some good success depending on where your bottleneck is.  One caveat - When I do code optimization I always like to profile the code, even informally to get an idea of where the bottlenecks are.  This will help identify where the time is being spent i.e. file io, network latency, resource contention, not enough cpu cycles etc...

For others who may not be familiar with the Expectation Maximization algorithm a very nice introduction is in Motion Segmentation using EM - a short tutorial, by Yair Weiss. Let us assume we have M data points and N classes/models.

In the EM algorithm there are two steps: Computing the distance between data points and models and Updating our model weights using weighted least squares.

Step 1 - Expectation stage

```
for data_point in M:
  for current_model in N:
    compute distance or residual between data_point and current_model
```

Step 2 - Maximization stage

```
for each model, compute weighted least squares solving for the model parameters
  This requires solving N weighted least square problems where the size is 
  dependent on the number of parameters in the model that will be solved for.
```

Your bottleneck may be in the stage of computing the residuals or distances between the data points and the models stage 1 - E Step.  In this stage the computations are all independent.  I would consider the first stage as embarassingly parallel and quite amenable to parallel computation using parallel map reduce or some other tools in python. I have good success using IPython for such tasks, but there are other good python packages as well.

Comment: Okay, so I should parallelize the expectation stage and leave the maximization stage sequential? Could you give me a simple code example?

Thank you so much for helping with my question.